# TextFormField in AlertDialog not validating

Tags: validation, flutter, dart

So im having a issue where my validator in my TextFormField is not validating the value in the text field...

Below is my code for the whole Alert Dialog:

```
showDialog(
            barrierDismissible: false,
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return WillPopScope(
                  onWillPop: () async => false,
                  child: AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Full name :'),
                    content: Form(
                      key: _nameFormKey,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: displayNameController,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (!(value.length > 5) && value.isNotEmpty) {
                            return 'Please set your full name';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      new FlatButton(
                        child: Text('CONFIRM'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_nameFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            // prefs.setString(
                            //     'displayName', displayNameController.text);
                            // Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            // displayNameController.clear();
                            print('validated');
                          }
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ));
            })
```

It printed 'validated' in the debug console when i clicked on the button even when there is no value entered in the text field

Comment: why you have added '!' in validator??

Comment: errr.. i dont really know how to write a correct validation logic for a full name, to me that seems to be the correct logic.. or do u suggest another logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for Full name validation I do something like this:

in your TextFormField, validator try to do such thing

```
validator: (value) {
  if (value.isEmpty) {

    // name is empty, don't validate
    return S.of(context).key('errorEmptyField');

  } else if (value.split(' ').length < 2) {

    // name contains only 1 word, don't validate
    return S.of(context).key('errorOnlyFirstName');

  } else if (value.length < 5) {

    // name is too short, don't validate
    return S.of(context).key('errorNameTooShort');

  }
  // validate
  return null;
},
```

I return error string to display to user, but you can return bools or whatever you want, anyway this is a basic full name validation logic.

Comment: @ETCasual Nice thanks, ofc I've edited the answer because the sort check was wrong, now it's better :)